# How do I add another printer to Brother ControlCenter4?

Tags: printer, network-printer, brother-printer

I just installed a second printer on my computer. The first printer was a Brother DCP-7065DN, while the second is a Brother MFC-L2740DW. On opening ControlCenter4, I am not able to see the second model from ControlCenter4. I have installed the drivers available for this printer and I am able to print.

How can I add the second model to ControlCenter4?

[image: Only one model available on Brother ControlCenter4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only installed the printer drivers, you will not be able to use ControlCenter4 with the printer. In order to see the model added to ControlCenter4, visit the Brother site and install the [Full Driver & Software Package](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl2740dw_us_eu_as&os=93&dlid=dlf100997_000&flang=8&type3=11) for your printer model. Doing this will allow you to use ControlCenter4 with the new printer.

Comment: i installed another Brother Printer profile but can't see it under the Pull-down menu of the Control Center 4. CC4 refuses to the scanner. It goes to PaperPort by default now and it is not the software I prefer. (Prior to this I did install the Full Package and New Firmware but still, CC4 does not recognize the new device).